# Клик по iconContent у метки с собственным изображением

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, yandex-geocoding-api

Я создаю иконку с собственным изображением и с подписью следующим образом:

```
// Создаём макет содержимого.
    MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div style="display: inline; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold; background-color: #FFFFFF;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
    ),

    myPlacemarkWithContent = new ymaps.Placemark([55.661574, 37.573856], {
        hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки с контентом',
        balloonContent: 'А эта — новогодняя',
        iconContent: 'Подпись метки должна быть кликабельна'
    }, {
        // Опции.
        // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
        iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
        // Своё изображение иконки метки.
        iconImageHref: 'images/ball.png',
        // Размеры метки.
        iconImageSize: [48, 48],
        // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
        // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
        iconImageOffset: [-24, -24],
        // Смещение слоя с содержимым относительно слоя с картинкой.
        iconContentOffset: [50, 15],
        // Макет содержимого.
        iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
    });
```

В итоге клик можно сделать только по изображению метки. Возможно ли добавить клик на подпись метки (и чтобы курсор над текстом метки был pointer)?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в опции передать ключ cursor: 'pointer' (тип строка)
А лучше используй документацию по [PlaceMarker](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html)

Answer (score 0):

Для всех пользовательских макетов активную область нужно задавать самостоятельно через [options.shape](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/layouts.html) (см. "Интерактивность геообъектов").

У Яндекса есть [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape/) отрисовки шейпа метки в виде многоугольника путем указания координат его вершин — такой же фигурой нужно будет обрисовать подпись метки в вашем случае:

```
iconShape: {   
            type: 'Polygon',
            // Полигон описывается в виде трехмерного массива. Массив верхнего уровня содержит контуры полигона. 
            // Первый элемента массива - это внешний контур, а остальные - внутренние.
            coordinates: [
                // Описание внешнего контура полигона в виде массива координат.
                [[-28,-76],[28,-76],[28,-20],[12,-20],[0,-4],[-12,-20],[-28,-20]]
                // , ... Описание внутренних контуров - пустых областей внутри внешнего.
            ]
        }
```